# how to resolve circular reference in Django model?

Tags: django-models

I'm converting an old app from ASP.NET + MSSQL to Django + Postgres.  The existing design looks like this:

```
create table foo 
( id  integer
, name varchar(20)
, current_status_id integer null
)

create table foo_status
( id integer
, foo_id integer
, status_date datetime
, status_description varchar(100)
)
```

So each foo has a multiple foo_history records, but there is a denormalized field, current_status_id, that points to the last history record.

To convert the data, I just defined foo.current_status_id as an IntegerField, not as a ForeignKey, because Postgres would (correctly) gripe about missing foreign keys no matter which table I loaded first.

Now that I've converted the data, I'd like to have all the foreign-key goodness again, for things like querying.  Is there a good way to handle this besides changing the model from IntegerField before I do a syncdb to ForeignKey afterward?

Answer (score 0):

A few points about how django works:

- `./manage.py syncdb` does not modify existing tables.  You can modify your model fields and run syncdb, but your db will stay intact.  If you need do need this functionality, use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/index.html).
- When creating a new instance `x` with a `myfk` `ForeignKey` field, and setting it's `x.myfk_id` by assigning it an integer and `x.save()`ing it, the constraint is checked only on the db level:  Django will not throw an exception if the referenced records are missing.  Therefore, you can first create the tables without the constraints (either by using IntegerFields+syncdb as you suggested, or carefully running a modified `.manage.py sqlall` version of the ForeignKeys version), load your data, and then `ALTER TABLE` your db manually.